# Android studio unable to see exception logs in debug mode only

Tags: android, exception, gradle, google-analytics, android-studio-2.1

I am unable to see exception logs in Android Studio version 2.1.0 in debug mode and able to see it release mode

I am using following gradle version

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

Following is Google Play Services lib

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

I am using google analytics and I have also added following code

```
t.enableExceptionReporting(false);
```

Still I am not able to see exception logs in debug mode. What can be the reason?

Comment: Hmm `enableExceptionReporting(false);`... You do know what false means, yes? Also, only uncaught exceptions are reported with that

Comment: Does the issue still occur in the latest version of play-services (9.0.2)?

Comment: I am using version 8.4.0 and cant upgrade it to 9.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Go to View -> Tool Windows -> Android Monitor and voila you see the logs of your application.

Comment: I believe the question is about Google Analytics, and not Android Studio